# Resolve handlers using Factory via IOC container

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, simple-injector

I have the task of refactoring a monolithic MVC application (1 controller action with over 1000 lines) into something more manageable.

The purpose of the program is to parse collections of different types, one by one, in a specific order.

Here is an example of a proposed 'better' solution...

```
public interface IFruit
{
}

public class Banana : IFruit
{
}

public class Apple : IFruit
{
}

public interface IFruitHandler<in TFruit> where TFruit : IFruit
{
    void Handle(IEnumerable<TFruit> fruit);
}

public class BananaHandler : IFruitHandler<Banana>
{
    public void Handle(IEnumerable<Banana> fruit)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("break apart the bunch of bananas");

        foreach (var banana in fruit)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Peel the banana");
        }
    }
}

public class AppleHandler : IFruitHandler<Apple>
{
    public void Handle(IEnumerable<Apple> fruit)
    {
        foreach (var apple in fruit)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Slice the apple");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Throw the apple cores away");
    }
}
```

As you can see, each fruit has its own handler, and each handler implementation may differ slightly.
Some handlers do stuff before working through the collection, others do things afterward, some do things before AND after.

The application presents one object (via an MVC controller) with all the different fruit collections as properties (a big view model basically).  I would like some kind of mediator that can take all of these collections and pass them to the appropriate handler.

This is what i had in mind...

```
public class Mediator : IMediator
{
    private readonly Func<Type, IFruitHandler<IFruit>> handlerFactory;

    public Mediator(Func<Type, IFruitHandler<IFruit>> handlerFactory)
    {
        this.handlerFactory = handlerFactory;
    }

    public void Execute(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IFruit>> fruitBundles)
    {
        foreach (var bundle in fruitBundles)
        {
            if (!bundle.Any())
                continue;

            var handler = handlerFactory(bundle.First().GetType());
            handler.Handle(bundle);
        }
    }
}
```

A Fruit bundle will always contain only one fruit, and the bundles will be in a specific order.  The signature for Mediator.Execute is loose enough for one bundle to contain different fruits.  This should not happen.

The question is two-fold....

I can register all FruitHandlers with OpenGenerics...

```
container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(typeof(IFruitHandler<>),typeof(IFruitHandler<>).Assembly);
```

but I am having difficulties getting the registration correct for the factory - how do i register the factory with Simple Injector?

The Mediator / handler factory implementation feels awkward, as does the IFruit interface (its effectively just a marker) - would you change the design?

Comment: Do you actually need to pass the all the bananas into the banana handler and all the apples into the apple handler in one go or can you change all the fruit handlers to take one piece of fruit at a time?

Comment: you could handle one fruit, yes.  And then have a composite handler to loop the collection.  But this presents an issue where the handler does something before or after iterating the fruits.

Comment: But there's no guarantee that each `fruitBundle` has only one type of fruit

Comment: Good point.  There will be only one fruit type in each bundle, and they will be in a specific order too.

Comment: I find it hard to see what your application needs to do, since you replaced it with fruit. Could you explain those 'fruit' objects really are in your case? Can you describe what kind of logic you do before and after looping through the collection?

Comment: I ended up scrapping the proposed design above completely and going with a chain of responsibility type approach instead.  its working perfectly now.

Comment: Problem with these types of questions is that they're not really suited for Stackoverflow. So if you're interested in a more detailed design review for this or a next question, you can also post it on the [Simple Injector forum](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/discussions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the `Mediator` in the following way but it has some downsides:

- it uses `dynamic`
- the `Mediator` needs to reference the `Container` (although this is ok if you define this class in your composition root)

I feel the question is too general to be able to provide any specific advice on a better way to design your solution.

```
class Mediator : IMediator
{
    private readonly Container container;

    public Mediator(Container container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public void Handle(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IFruit>> fruitBundles)
    {
        foreach (var bundle in fruitBundles)
        {
            if (bundle.Any())
            {
                dynamic instance = bundle.First();
                this.Handle(instance, bundle);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Handle<T>(T instance, IEnumerable<IFruit> bundle)
        where T : IFruit
    {
        var handler = this.container.GetInstance<IFruitHandler<T>>();

        handler.Handle(bundle.Cast<T>());
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a valid solution so worth marking as the answer.  I've completely changed the proposed design now to use a chain of responsibility pattern.  It fits the problem much better, especially the strict ordering requirement.  Thanks for your input